# How to set up wifi pods at home with an existing router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have a bell home hub 2000, and I want to connect wifi pods to it. I wanted to know what is the best way to set it up.

The pods I'm looking at now is this one
https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B09VVV18D9/ref=emc_b_5_t

Some questions I have is?

1. Is tri band better than dual band if only phones and maybe 1-2 laptops will ever be connected?
2. Should I make it an AP mode for the pods, or disable the bell HH2000 wifi and set up a new wifi from the pods? I guess if I leave the bell wifi on, would it interfere with the pod wifi or somehow work together to make it better?
3. Would these pods work with the bell hub 2000, or am I only limited to the bell pods itself?
4. Can a switch be connected to a pod for additional LAN ports?

Ideally looking to set it up like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Start with the manual - freely available - https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/deco-x60/

Comment: You're going to want the only wifi to be produced by the new system (the old wifi will just be confusing, and not capable of joining the mesh you're trying to set up (unless it's also wifi 6 capable; it's difficult to tell from the docs available online).

Comment: The bell HH2000 is not wifi6. So then for sure, turning off the wifi there is best? If it was wifi6, would it be better to leave it on?